# Getting the number of Facebook likes for a URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know there are several related answers on SO, but none seem to answer my question.

I would like to know if there is way to get the number of likes for a URL, using Graph API 2.2.

I know how to obtain this info via FQL or REST API, but those are deprecated.

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=some_url

This returns the number of "shares", which is a total of like + shares + whatever. I need only the number of likes.

https://graph.facebook.com/some_opengraph_id/likes?summary=true

This returns the number of likes, but that total seems to be much lower than what a query on FQL link_stat table would return. Also /likes returns a list of likes, but it doesn't seem to be a complete list.

So is it possible to do this via Graph API or only FQL / REST support this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same behavior, but unfortunately afaik there are no other options currently. If you have a v2.0 app, you can continue to use FQL until August 7th, 2016.